# Не работает classlist.add

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, frontend

Что делать при нажатие на кнопку текст должен двигаться в право а потом обратно вернуться но он двигается когда загружен сайт помогите пожалуйста кто поможет большое спасибо

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Test.css">
</head>
<body>
<span id="Text">Текст</span>
<button id="Button" onclick="ButtonClick()">Нажать</button>
</body>
<script src="Test.js"></script>
</html>
```

Css:

```
@keyframes Textanim {
    0%{
        padding-left: 0;
    }
    50%{
        padding-left: 100px;
    }
    100%{
        padding-left: 0;
    }
}
#Text{
    animation: Textanim 1s, infinite linear;
}
```

Js:

```
let text = document.getElementById("Text");

function ButtonClick()
{
    if(!text.classList.add("Text"))
    {
        text.classList.add("Text");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

classlist.add у вас не работает, потому что, ваш код никакого класса не добавляет. Точнее вы пытаетесь добавить ID синтаксисом для добавления класса. Если порпавить ваш код, чтобы работал, то можно так. А текст должен двигаться при каждом нажатии на кнопку?:

```js
let text = document.getElementById("Text");
let btn = document.getElementById("Button");


btn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
text.classList.add('text');
//setTimeout(
//()=>{text.classList.remove('text')}, 1000)
})

text.addEventListener('animationend', ()=>{
text.classList.remove('text')
})
```

```css
@keyframes Textanim {
    0%{
        padding-left: 0;
    }
    50%{
        padding-left: 100px;
    }
    100%{
        padding-left: 0;
    }
}
.text{
    animation: Textanim 1s, infinite linear;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Test.css">
</head>
<body>
<span id="Text">Текст</span>
<button id="Button">Нажать</button>
</body>
<script src="Test.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Да при каждом нажатии

Comment: И каким то образом в браузере тоже самое когда обновляю страницу анимация играет один раз без нажатие на кнопку

Comment: Поправил ответ. Смотрите сейчас. Самое простое решение - это сначала присвоить класс, а после завершения анимации (у вас это 1 сек), убрать класс с помощью сетТаймаут.
Классы в CSS стилизируется с точкой .class{}, а id через #

Comment: @Макск переделайте на [на это](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event) так анимация гарантированно отработает

Comment: @Айболит да, спасибо :) запамятовал

Comment: Cдесь работает а в браузерах нет перезагружаю страницу один раз работает анимация нажимаю кнопку уже не работает проверил на FireFox и Google Chrome

Comment: @Half вы точно скопировали текст и работает как раньше? Странно. А тут https://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: @Макск Работает а в браузерах нет

Comment: запятую наверно убрать надо вот здесь : Textanim 1s, infinite linear

Comment: @Айболит Все равно

Comment: @Half префиксы добавьте - может быть в них проблема

Comment: Забросил код к себе. В хроме работает нормально. Автор, проверьте, сохранили ли вы изменения (редктор VS Code) Ctrl+s . Если там всё ок, то уже помочь не смогу.

Comment: У меня Web Storm.....

Comment: У меня такой же редактор.

Comment: Странно в двух браузерах проверяю ничего

Comment: Извиняюсь вы просто быстро код js изменили не заметил спасибо все работает